# Four rational numbers whose product is 10 and whose sum is 0

Tags: mathematics, calculation-puzzle

It has been shown that every positive integer is the product of four rational numbers whose sum is 0.

Thus:

```
3 = (242/75) x (-25/6) x (25/22) x (-54/275) while 
0 = (242/75) + (-25/6) + (25/22) + (-54/275).
```

Find four rational numbers whose product is 10 and whose sum is 0.

Comment: The source of this problem is https://doi.org/10.4169/amer.math.monthly.123.10.989.

Comment: Is there a reason you're insisting on code formatting for your math? The point of code formatting is to signal to the computer that you're using code, which isn't the case here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> We are looking for rational numbers, so we can search for integers a,b,c,d,x where
> a+b+c+d = 0
> abcd = 10x^4
> The most simple solution (if it exists) would use one 5 (the larger prime factor) and powers of 2.
> Since 5 is odd , we must use 1
> We can use 5 and 1 with same sign, leading to
> -2.-4.5.1 = 10x^4
> We can use 5 and 1 with different sign, leading to
> -1.-8.5.4 = 10x^4
> The second one gives x=2, giving a solution:

> -1/2,-8/2,5/2,4/2